# How to modify existing conda install to fix bug?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am running into an Anaconda bug described in this Github issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2965

The reporter indicates that if we makes some changes to Anaconda, he can fix the problem. I have installed Anaconda on my Max (OS X 10.11.6), and I am having the trouble reported by this issue while following instructions to install TensorFlow. I'm wondering whether someone can tell me how to find and modify my Conda installation to test out the proposed bug fix listed in the issue? Also are there files I can simply modify or will I need to recompile or reinstall after? I am a newbie to this sort of thing, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Go to the directory where you'd normally type `source bin/activate` except type `vim bin/activate` or whatever your favorite text editor is, and make the adjustments exactly as described. He even says what line they're on.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Part of my question is where activate is stored

Comment: It is stored in bin in each virtual env. I do not know where the central one lives that they all presumably get copied from. Check site-packages in your Python install